# login page won't redirect to the secure page

Tags: authentication

The login form won't redirect to the cloud.php.. i hav created session.. may i know wat is the problem..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MyCloud-Login</title>
<?php



//$un = 'abc';
//$pw = 'abc';

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "mycloud_zymichost_register";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "pass";

 $conn = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

 mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn );

 if (isset($_POST['login'])){

//$un = $_POST['name'];
$em = $_POST['email'];
$pw = $_POST['pass'];
//$un = mysql_real_escape_string($un);
$em = mysql_real_escape_string($em);
$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($pw);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM Register WHERE email = '$em' AND pass = '$pw'";
 //$query = "INSERT INTO Register (name,email,pass) VALUES ('$un','$em','$pw')";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());  


// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

// Jump to secured page
header('Location: cloud.html');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location: login.php');
}
 }
?>




<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
header('Location: cloud.php');
}

?>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>My Cloud</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Login

<form action="login.php" method="get" name="form">


<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
</div>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="pass">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value=""  />
</div>
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" name="login" value="submit-value">Login</button>
</form>


</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Henry</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The login form won't redirect to the cloud.php.. i hav created session.. may i know wat is the problem..

Comment: Based on this and other questions you've asked, I would suggest invest some time into learning about the technologies you're attempting to leverage instead of asking the community to walk you through it.

Comment: ya, i really lack of knowledge on this, bt due to the time i left.. i gt no time to study it now.. ur help is appreciated.. i gonna submit this final year project by april, yet i still stuck in the login..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the header function after any output is sent. Visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MyCloud-Login</title>
```

I seem to remember even blank lines causing issues with this as well. Move the top piece and get rid of blank lines and try again. There may be other issues but that is one of them.

Comment: den how can i redirect the pagE?

Comment: There is tons of useful tutorials explaining how to do this. [link](http://google.com?q=simple%20login%20system%20php)